# Cordova Plugin to Interact with voice commands

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

Is there any Voice Command Plugin for Cordova? (Ok Google Stuff ).

I have tried to build one my own, which I feel like need some assistance. Where can I find some help if Im to build my own plugin.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What exactly would you be using it for? Voice recognition or as an assistant?

Comment: Voice assistance. I want my cordova app to handle stuff like Ok Google, Book a taxi.